# How do you build OpenLDAP libraries on Windows using Msys2 and MinGW?

Tags: c, windows, openldap, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm trying to build OpenLDAP on Windows. I'm having extreme difficulty doing so.

I started to follow the directions outlined [here](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/302.html), but quickly realized that it was out of date.

I then found [this](https://bowmansolutions.com/mingw-openldap/), and realized it wasn't quite right either.

I finally found [this](http://www.openldap.org/its/index.cgi/Incoming?id=8383;selectid=8383), and experienced the exact bug that this guy is experiencing. However, when I try his work around (commenting out line 1116 in portable.h) I ran into more issues.

Is there a canonical source for building this library?

I'm using:

- Windows 7 Professional.
- Msys2 (x86_64 20160205 from [here](https://msys2.github.io/))
- OpenSSL (version 1.0.1r from [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.1/openssl-1.0.1r.tar.gz))
- rxspencer (alpha 3.8.g7 from [here](https://github.com/garyhouston/rxspencer/archive/alpha3.8.g7.tar.gz))
- OpenLDAP (version 2.4.44 from [here](ftp://ftp.openldap.org/pub/OpenLDAP/openldap-release/openldap-2.4.44.tgz))

Step 0:

Compile rxspencer

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

Step 1:

Compile OpenSSL using a Visual Studio 2010 x64 command prompt

```
perl Configure no-ssl2 VC-WIN64A --prefix=d:\temp\openssl\x64
./ms/do_win64a.bat

nmake -f ms\nt.mak
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
cd out32
..\ms\test
```

Step 2:

Modify the path so that configure will be able to see rxspencer

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

Step 3:

```
env \
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/rxspencer" \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/c/work/openssl/lib:/usr/local/lib" \
LDFLAGS="-L/c/work/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib" \
CPPFLAGS="-I/c/work/openssl/include" \
LIBS="-lssl -lrxspencer" \
./configure \
--enable-shared \
--enable-static \
--with-tls \
--disable-bdb \
--disable-hdb \
2>&1 | tee output_config.log
```

This works. Excellent!

Step 4:

```
make depend 2>&1 | tee output_makedepend.log
```

This works. Excellent!

Step 5:

Comment out line 1116 from include/portable.h

Step 6:

```
make 2>&1 | tee output_make.log
```

Watch a bunch of errors appear that look like this:

```
In file included from init.c:25:0:
back-mdb.h:71:2: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'
  uint32_t mi_dbenv_flags;
  ^
back-mdb.h:84:2: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'
  uint32_t mi_rtxn_size;
  ^
back-mdb.h:86:2: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'
  uint32_t mi_txn_cp_min;
  ^
back-mdb.h:87:2: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'
  uint32_t mi_txn_cp_kbyte;
  ^
init.c: In function 'mdb_db_open':
init.c:88:2: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'
  uint32_t flags;
```

Add:

```
#ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
#include <stdint.h>
#endif
```

to the top of

```
servers/slapd/back-mdb/back-mdb.h
```

make again...

Now I have a bunch of errors that look like this:

```
symdummy.c:1:5: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant
 int ".refptr.ad_index_mutex"();
     ^
symdummy.c:2:5: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant
 int ".refptr.ad_undef_mutex"();
     ^
symdummy.c:3:5: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant
 int ".refptr.at_oc_cache"();
 ^
```

pointing to something going wrong with servers/slapd.def?

What am I doing wrong here? Am I doing anything wrong and the build just doesn't work at all for Windows?

Comment: Stop it and get them from http://userbooster.de.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose? I want to build the library, not get it from some random German company I've never heard of.

Comment: Adding these two bugs from OpenLDAP project's own bug tracking system for reference: [7878](http://www.openldap.org/its/index.cgi/Incoming?id=7878) and [8383](http://www.openldap.org/its/index.cgi/Incoming?id=8383).

Comment: It depends on whether the purpose is to have something that works so you can start building your actual application, or to waste your time building software that others have already built for you. Another possible source is the Cygwin project, if you like that sort of thing, and another is CDS Silver.

Answer (score 2):

quite late for this.

I recently succeeded with

Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Msys2 x86_64 20160205

OpenLDAP 2.4.46 <== different from you

I disabled hdb and bdb same as you did as well. I enabled-shared lib, but not sure if they got compiled.

I notice this may not be the full list of what you want, just trying to share.

And it is thanks to your help I was able to overcome that portable.h and init.c problem.

Then my `make depend` and `make` succeeded without problem. I have done some simple test with it the slapd is working for me, are able to ldapsearch, ldapadd and connect to it from ldapAdmin.

during make depend, I did see the nt_err.c problem and have to manually copy it from openldap-2.4.46/libraries/liblber/nt_err.c to /openldap-2.4.46/servers/slapd/slapi to skip that warning. But I cannot solve the netdb.h header missing problem, none the less it still worked.