# How do I get .lib instead of .a as the output of OpenLDAP build?

Tags: openssl, openldap, msys2

Followed the links

[How do you build OpenLDAP libraries on Windows using Msys2 and MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435795/how-do-you-build-openldap-libraries-on-windows-using-msys2-and-mingw)

http://developer.covenanteyes.com/building-openssl-for-visual-studio/

Windows 2008 R2 x64

MSYS2 msys2-x86_64-20180531

OpenSSL 1.0.2

OpenLDAP 2.5

followed the bugs [7878](http://www.openldap.org/its/index.cgi/Incoming?id=7878) and [8383](http://www.openldap.org/its/index.cgi/Incoming?id=8383) for the alternatives and the build is successful.

How do I get .lib instead of .a as the output of OpenLDAP build in MSYS2?

Comment: Note: you shouldn't build stuff that will end up in the same process using more than one toolchain. Either pick *VStudio* or *MinGW* and build both *OpenSSL* and *OpenLDAP* with it. If you need to build a *.lib*, use the former option.

Comment: trying to find sane build instructions for openldap on Windows. couldn't find any so trying cross-platform tools.

Comment: A quick browse on *Openldap*'s *configure* only revealed *Cygwin* or *MinGW* build targets (no *VStudio*). So apparently there's no way to do what you want (unless you want to rename *.a* to *.lib* but that would simply be crap). So, the closest thing to have smth working is to build both tools with *Cygwin* or *MinGW* (*OpenSSL* build supports both toolchains as well).